# Call Perl script from Thunderbird Javascript

Tags: javascript, perl, firefox, firefox-addon, thunderbird

I wrote a perl script that handles some data automatically. However, I face a problem when I try to call the script from my thunderbird extension that is naturally written in javascript.

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                     .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("/usr/bin/perl");

// create an nsIProcess
var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(file);

// Run the process.
// If first param is true, calling thread will be blocked until
// called process terminates.
// Params are used to pass command-line arguments
// to the process
var args = ["package/myperlscript.pl", "some arguments];
process.run(true, args, args.length);
```

I guess I have the perl script placed at the wrong location. I tried various ones, but I could not get it work. If that is my major mistake, where is the base path that the javascript file expects?

Comment: I suggest your first arg may need to be "perl myperlscrript.pl". You may also need to supply the full bath to perl.

Comment: This should work fine, I used to do stuff like this, like here I do it on mac i run iconutil: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/a8a83786d7a1efc78a80 here i wrote a long thing that uses promise to run and then resolve, its basically the iconutil thing though, i just made it promise based: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/f605f648cab355e56648#file-_ff-addon-snippet-bashtofile-js-L198 that works on all unix

Comment: thanks, that sounds promising. still, perl seems to be initiated correctly, so the arguments are the problems. where do you place the myperlscript.pl?

Comment: @Dave it can be anywhere on your HD. If you package it with your addon you may need to copy it and store it outside of the addon as addons are zipped by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Made it with a hardcoded path.